# Why does VNC eat certain characters?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, vnc, linux-mint

I often use VNC to connect to my desktop upstairs using a laptop downstairs over my home network. I tunnel the VNC connection via SSH.

The problem I keep running into is that I'll attempt to type a `!` or a `:` or even a captial `A` and it will come across the wire as a `1`, `;`, or `a` respectively. Is this something I can fix? It's really REALLY annoying while one is programming to have to pop open character map and find a colon and copy/paste it in each time.

Running Ubuntu 10.04 upstairs, Linux Mint 10 downstairs.

Comment: sounds like a shift delay problem that has been discussed before....don't think there was a resolution.  the previous question related to RDP though.  it's still shift delay or multi-key press not being sent

Comment: @aking1012 is right. I've seen this specifically on LogMeIn software, where either the Shift isn't detected, or it stays on for two keypresses.

Comment: It's really weird, it works for certain characters but not for others. Uppercase letters that don't work with shift _do_ work with Caps-Lock, but this obviously doesn't help with colons and exclamation marks. So this is a problem with VNC in general, then? I'm using x11vnc if that helps, but I have noticed this problem elsewhere.

Comment: we're back to the two keypress at the same time issue.  you might be able to get around it by sending it as a control character or hex character, but that's an ugly hack and not a solution

Comment: you could also try an on-screen keyboard, again ugly and hackish

Comment: Where might the bug exist, client or server? VNC protocol or implementor? I'll see if I can reproduce/solve the problem with other viewers. (Can't really try other servers, I need x11vnc for what I'm doing.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `-xkb` to my invocation of `x11vnc` did the trick:

```
x11vnc -rfbauth passwordfile -o logfile -forever -bg -localhost -xkb
```

No more eaten characters!